# Recursive menu in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am building a recursive menu in the following way:

```
public static function tree()
{
    return static::with(implode('.', array_fill(0, 100, 'children')))->where('parent_id', '=', '0')
        ->join('company_components', 'id', '=', 'company_components.component_id')
        ->where('company_components.company_id', '=', auth('api')->user()->with('company')->first()->company_id)
        ->orderBy('id')
        ->get();
}
```

I get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "parent_id":0,
    "name":"Cuentas",
    "url":"",
    "icon":"fa fa-user",
    "deleted_at":null,
    "created_at":"2019-05-26 18:57:02",
    "updated_at":"2019-05-26 18:57:02",
    "company_id":1,
    "component_id":1,
    "children":[
        {
          "id":2,
          "parent_id":1,
          "name":"Crear Cuenta",
          "url":"/account/create",
          "icon":"fa fa-circle-o",
          "deleted_at":null,
          "created_at":null,
          "updated_at":null,
          "children":[]
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

How can I avoid the empty array of the last elements (which no longer have children)?

Is there any way that the element is not created if "children" if it does not have more children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $this->cleanMenu($menu);

    public function cleanMenu($tree)
    {
        foreach($tree as $t) {
            if (!$t->children->count() > 0) {
                unset($t['children']);
            } else {
                $this->cleanMenu($t->children);
            }
        }
    }
```

If there is a solution solving from the model without the need to iterate again, it would be phenomenal!

I hope help